# How do I set relative bar width in altair?

Tags: altair

How do I use relative bar width with altair? According to vega-lite [documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/bar.html#relative-bar-width). This code:

```json
{
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 0.7}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "timeUnit": "month",
      "field": "date"
    },
    "y": {
      "aggregate": "mean",
      "field": "precipitation"
    }
  }
}
```

produces a bar that occupies 70% of each x band.

How do I set this in altair? If I use something like:

```py
.mark_bar(width={'band':0.7})
```

I got an error about width not being a number.

How do I set relative bar widths in altair?

Answer (score 1):

You could also set the padding between the bars instead, using `padding` in the `scale` argument of the encoding field. For mark_bar, for example, setting it to 0.3, would set the bar width to 70% of the 'tick space'.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.seattle_weather()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('month(date):O', scale=alt.Scale(padding=0.3)),
    y='mean(precipitation):Q'    
)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the current development version of Altair on GitHub, what you suggested should work. [As per this post](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/discussions/2601#discussioncomment-2723147), you should also be able to do the following:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.seattle_weather()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar(
    width=alt.RelativeBandSize(0.7)
).encode(
    x='month(date):O',
    y='mean(precipitation):Q'    
)
```

Comment: I tried this code and it throws the error "AttributeError: module 'altair' has no attribute 'RelativeBandSize'"

Comment: @ngolos This is for the current development version of Altair installed via GitHub

Comment: Understood, thanks! 
I thought there should be also a way to write ExprRef for this task, but i can’t figure out how to do it)